# JQuery using Prepend to dynamically set ID

Tags: jquery, dynamic, prepend

I want to use prepend to dynamically attached a div with an ID of the container it's beeing attached too. I can't seem to make it work for each element, at the moment it just use the same ID.

HTML

```
<div class="advanced-slider" id="About" >
        <p> Content </p>
</div>
<div class="advanced-slider" id="Main" >
        <p> Content </p>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.advanced-slider').wrap('<div class="slider-container"><div class="slider-wrapper"></div></div>');

$('.slider-container').prepend('<div class="slider-title" id="' + $(this).find('.advanced-slider').attr('id') + '-title"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` in your code refers to `window` object, try the following.

```
$('.slider-container').prepend(function(){
   return '<div class="slider-title" id="' + $(this).find('.advanced-slider').prop('id') + '-title"></div>';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aPJs5/

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for quick response ;) | One quick question, is it better to use prop over attr?

Comment: @user1872133 You are welcome, yes, `prop` method is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".slider-container").prepend(function(){
    return "<div class=\"slider-title\" id=\"" 
              + $(".advanced-slider", this).attr("id") 
              + "-title\"></div>";
});
```